# auto compile generated visual studio files without adding to project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compilation, generated-code

I created a project in VS2013 that generates C++ source files, and I want it to also compile the generated files to a static-lib without having to add the generated files to the project.
Ideally I want something like a custom build command that compiles everything that resides in the directory holding the generated files, but works inside VS and is triggered anytime the project regenerates the files.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can do that using `CMake` to generate your Visual Studio project but `CMake` takes a while to learn